# C# Code running really slow

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hy, I have a int[] x with 10000 indexes, and I`m using a code like this to put every value in a newline in a textbox, but my code will take atleast a couple minuts to fill the textbox, is there a quickier way to do the same?

```
for ( int x = 0; X < 10000; x++)
{
    textBox1.Text += randomNumber[x] + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: This is a standard example of the [Schlemiel the Painter Algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, use a string builder for things like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(10000); 
for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
{
    builder.AppendLine(randomNumber[x]);
}
textBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Otherwise you are 'coughing up a string', a common pitfall to new programmers.  [Here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) is a great blog post from Joel Spolsky describing common pitfalls with strings and immutability.

Comment: You should consider setting `StringBuilder` initial capacity.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Does that really make much sense if you don't set it to a reasonable upper bound first? It seems like the few initial resizes might be dwarfed by the fact you still have to copy several times more bytes into the final size buffer, and all the resizes between your initial capacity and the target size. (Which are obviously all larger copies than the ones before.)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: In .NET 4.0, `StringBuilder` is implemented as a list of "chunks" rather than a single list of characters as in previous versions. So setting the initial capacity doesn't provide the same benefit as in previous versions. See http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2010/08/25/StringAndStringBuilderInNET4.aspx for details.

Comment: Use `builder.AppendLine()` rather than `builder.Append(string + Environment.NewLine)`

Comment: @JimMischel Quite interesting. Thank's for the link!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether `randomNumber` collection size is `10000` or not, but if it is, you can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx) method:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, randomNumber);
```

It will use `StringBuilder` internally anyway, but is better to read.

Answer (score 0):

Build the string first, then put its value in the textbox (instead of appending text to the text box 10,000 times).